# What is the hashtag #다들_첫뮤_뭐보셨나요?

Tags: meaning, korean-culture, phrase-meaning

> 다들_첫뮤_뭐보셨나요

is [trending on twitter](https://twitter.com/hashtag/%EB%8B%A4%EB%93%A4_%EC%B2%AB%EB%AE%A4_%EB%AD%90%EB%B3%B4%EC%85%A8%EB%82%98%EC%9A%94?src=tren)...but why?  ***what does it mean?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like:

> 다들 = Everyone 
>   첫뮤 = 첫뮤지컬 = First musical
>   뭐보셨나요 = What did you see?

So, "What was everyone's first musical that you saw?"

Comment: That's got to be it, looking through the tweets, they seem to all be musicals; for instance these three: `맘마미아`, `캣츠`, `난타`

Comment: For the sake of completeness: I think most Koreans will have difficulty figuring out 첫뮤->첫뮤지컬.  It probably works because people using this hashtag are musical fans so they already know what they're talking about.